# How to enable AzureMonitorAgent (AMA) on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

While trying to install the AzureMonitorAgent (AMA) following [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-windows-client#install-the-agent), I am getting below error.

[image]

How to install the AMA from the VM extensions menu from Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to enable AzureMonitorAgent (AMA) on Azure VM

You can add the `VM` to the `Data collection` rule to install the `Extension` and enable system identity in the `VM` or you can install the `AzureMonitorWindowsAgent` manually using PowerShell to enable `Logs` on an `Azure VM`

1. Install the `AzureMonitorWindowsAgent` extension on an `Azure VM` using PowerShell.

```
Set-AzVMExtension -Name AzureMonitorWindowsAgent -ExtensionType AzureMonitorWindowsAgent -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Monitor -ResourceGroupName <RG-Name>-VMName <vmname> -Location "West Europe" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.1" -EnableAutomaticUpgrade $true
```

**Result:**

[image]

2. Add the `Azure VM` to the `Data collection` rule by following these steps.

Go to **Monitor > Data Collection Rules > Create.**

[image]

2. Add the `VMs` to the `Data Collection rule` on resource tab

[image]

3. Add `data sources` and `destination` as below

[image]

**Destination**

[image]

4. Once the complete all the steps the `VM` is reporting to the `log analytics workspaces` configured in the `DCR` as below.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I am curious, if the extension is available on the marketplace? I was trying to find by name but no result.